# Meaning of "Server Problem" inspection severity at Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, code-inspection

What is a "Server Problem" severity about? What inspections is it valid for?

[image: Severity levels at Intellij Idea]

According to default order at Severity editor, it's weaker than "Weak warning". But at the same time, appearances of "Server Problem" are marked with an orange underscore and are even more noticeable than the "Warning" severity.

[image: Severity editor]

I could not find any inspection with such severity at default configuration. Also, the [latest Idea documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-inspection-severities.html) says nothing about this severity.

My best guess is that it may be designed for performance-related problems. Or maybe for inspections that find problems with application server configuration (security settings, filesystem access, classpathes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Server problem"* is the severity level for errors or warnings obtained from server. So it's a severity for an error/warning that comes from something like TeamCity. Probably more clear name for it would be "Build Server Problem". Please follow the issue already created for this usability problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133460. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense.